# Trying to fix ping spikes in counter strike

Tags: networking, games

I found a reddit post with instructions on how to eliminate ping spikes in csgo but i ran into an error.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-gtk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wicd-gtk
```

An answer would be appreciated ;)
P.S. Sorry if this is not an appropriate question and im making a fool out of myself, im very new to linux but have been enjoying it so far!

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Unfortunately it would appear wicd-gtk is removed in 20.04, which is a pity because Network-Manager is awful. Ref- https://reposcope.com/package/wicd-gtk